# Type 'Custom TableViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UICollectionViewDataSource'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Type 'Custom TableViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UICollectionViewDataSource'.

I have created a project using Swift and have a UITableViewcontroller. and in UITableFooterView i added collection but i can't add UICollectionViewDataSource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Type 'TableViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UICollectionViewDataSource'

Check once your datasource method is delecared or not

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemInSection section: Int) -> Int;

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell;
```

if it is already declared , Check for types in your code Like - use `numberOfItemsInSection` instead `numberOfItemInSection`.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you have implemented the following methods

```
- collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:
- collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:
```